# Giving Chronicles of Nchuleft to Urag - 'Fetch me that book' quest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I dont know if anyone else has had this problem but I went to Bleak Falls Barrow near when I first started playing the game and I got the book Chronicles of Nchuleft. The quest is back in my menu saying to go find the book. So I went back to Bleak Falls Barrow just to see if that would fix it and went through everything and the book isnt there but the arrow is pointing at the chest. I tried putting the book back in the chest but I cant remove it because its a quest item and the noise saying that a word of power is near is going but I have already got that word of power.
Anyone else been having this problem?
If so do you know how to fix it? (ps3)

Thanks :)

Comment: I think the real question is how do you pronounce Nchuleft?

Comment: @Gmnoob, silent N perhaps?  chew-left

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your game glitched.  W/out access to console commands, or loading a previous save, I don't believe there is a way to fix it.  Try talking to the quest giver just in case.

Reference:
http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Find_the_copy_of_Chronicles_of_Nchuleft

Answer (score 0):

I realize you're on console, but this is the first hit on google for this issue, and there *is* a solution for PC.

So, for you PC players:  type `setstage MGR20 20` in the console (hit `~`) to fix this issue.  If that doesn't work, try `setstage MGR20B 20`